# facebook wall-like ajax in yii's zii widget list

Tags: ajax, yii

I'm very new to yii, and I'm trying to integrate the facebook-wall-like style into my post list.

In short, I just want to add a "Load More" with ajax to load more posts at the bottom of the post list.

I know how to write ajax or html, but I don't know how to integrate this style into yii.

I'v tried the zii.widgets.CListView/CDetailView.. but I can't find ways to add ajax.

If there's anyone who knows the how-to, please share it with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [this extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiinfinite-scroll), it is a pager that adds infinite scroll like in twitter - when you get to the bottom of the page it loads more content via ajax. If you prefer to load more only once a button is pressed, i'm sure it's just a matter of overriding the button's onclick event.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want!